# Web API: AttributeRouting with typed parameter possible?

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

Is this possible?
For example,

```
    [GET("api/item/{id}/related")]
    public dynamic GetRelatdItemsById(string id, Filter filter)
    {
        // get items related by id and optionally filter by `filter`
    }
```

If this is possible, how should the query string be setup??

many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind that.  Just forgotten to use the `[FromUri]` attribute. :)

Comment: hi alex, just stumbled on your question but i couldn't make my querystring to work without having the {id}. For example, i have a GetUsers(int id)/GetUserByUserName(string username)/GetUserByName(string name). But, if the user has username=1234 or name=1234 we might have a valid 1234 id in the and database and all the routes will be mixed up. What i'd like to do is to have filters for the last 2 methods to get querystrings for filtering api/users/?username=1234 or api/users/?name=1234 . Do you have any idea how i could get this working? cheers